# Indefinite integral of $x^3+x+1/x^4+x^2+1$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I had come across a question as follows:

> Compute the integral
> $$\int_{}{(x^3+x+1)/(x^4+x^2+1)}dx$$

I tried a lot manipulating the numerator but I couldn't convert the terms into standard forms. Factorisation of the denominator didn't prove to be helpful either.
I have run out of ideas. Would someone please help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extended hint:
$$
\frac{x^3+x+1}{x^4+x^2+1}=\frac12\left[\frac1{x^2-x+1}+\frac{2x+1}{x^2+x+1}\right].
$$

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**
$$x^4+x^2+1=(x^4+2x^2+1)-x^2$$

Use the formula for difference of squares.

Comment: I used that but that did not help me.

Comment: @Shashwat1337 Once you have that, it is a standard partial fraction decomposition.